# Infinite loop 'try and if' under a method

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

1. Executing `menu()` and go to 1 or 2 or 3 is good to do its work.
2. But after passing by `getproduct(character)` and getting back to `menu()` and then if you choose number 3, it makes a bad loop.

I want to know why, and how to solve this problem...

```
def menu():

    menu = '1. ice\n2. cream\n3. quit'
    print(menu)
    
    try:
        order = int(input('choose one: '))
        
        if order == 1:
            c = 'ice'
            getproduct(c)
        elif order == 2:
            c = 'cream'
            getproduct(c)
            
        elif order == 3:
            exit()
            
        else: menu()
        
    except ValueError: menu()


def getproduct(character):

    toping = int(input('1. ice or 2. cream?'))
    
    try:
        if character == 'ice' and toping == 1:
            print(character + 'ice')
            menu()
        
        elif character == 'ice' and toping == 2:
            print(character + 'cream')
            menu()
        elif character == 'cream' and toping == 1:
            print(character + 'ice')
            menu()
        elif character == 'cream' and toping == 2:
            print(character + 'cream')
            menu()
        else: getproduct(character)
    except: getproduct(character)
    
        
menu()
```

Comment: What do you mean by bad loop

Comment: I think he means it drops on a `3` choice because he is trying to call `exit()`

Comment: Your functions are mutually recursive. I'm sure you don't want that. Perhaps you mean that `getproduct()` should `return` to `menu()`.

Comment: You should also look at [validating user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: bad loop means infinite loop

Comment: firstly I execute the menu(), it works good whatever i choose, but after passing by getproduct(character) and get back to the menu(), it does not work well. it is stuck by the 3rd 'if' which has exit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes on the code. First of all, you are using exit, that should not be used within files, instead of it, I use on my example the module sys (sys.exit(0)) that has the same goal.

On the other hand, you are using the input checks in an imprecise way, and looping should be different. In menus, I personally recommend using while loops.

Solution for your problem and a a couple of improvements (could be better):

```
import sys

def menu():
    menu = '1. ice\n2. cream\n3. quit'

    while True:
        print(menu)
        try:
            order = int(input('choose one: '))
        except:
            print("Use a correct answer")
        else:
            if order == 1:
                c = 'ice'
                getproduct(c)
            elif order == 2:
                c = 'cream'
                getproduct(c)
            elif order == 3:
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                print("Use a correct answer")

def getproduct(character):
    topings = '1. ice or 2. cream?: '

    while True:
        print(topings)
        try:
            second_order = int(input())
        except:
            print("Use a correct answer")
        else:
            if character == 'ice' and second_order == 1:
                print(character + 'ice')
                break
            elif character == 'ice' and second_order == 2:
                print(character + 'cream')
                break
            elif character == 'cream' and second_order == 1:
                print(character + 'ice')
                break
            elif character == 'cream' and second_order == 2:
                print(character + 'cream')
                break
            else:
                print("Use a correct answer.")

menu()
```

Comment: btw, you don't need `sys.exit(0)`. I would prefer `return`.

Comment: @quamrana 
You are right, however, I usually use ```return``` in environments where it is clear that it is used to exit the procedure and ```sys.exit(0)``` in those in which you want to end the application.

In this case, both scenarios are the same so I agree

Comment: Thank you. this is what the way I wanted to do make.

Answer (score 0):

The `exit()` function works by raising the `SystemExit` type of exception, which propagates up the chain until there's nothing more to run and the program comes to a stop.

That it *is* an exception means that the code above where the `SystemExit` is raised is allowed to close resources and do other wind-down activities, so as not to break any external resources. However, it also means that a blank `except:` statement can catch the `SystemExit` and ignore it. Which is what's happening here.

```
def getproduct(character):

    toping = int(input('1. ice or 2. cream?'))
    
    try:
        ...
        # call to menu(), which calls exit()
    except: # this activates on ANY exception, including SystemExit
        getproduct(character)
```

In general, you should *almost never* use a raw `except` block, because of situations like this where it catches something you don't want it to. Instead, analyze the code inside the `try`, figure out what types of exceptions it would throw, and catch those. In your case, it's likely to be either `ValueError` or `TypeError`:

```
try:
    ...
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    getproduct(character)
```

or, if you're dead set on catching everything, you can write a special exception for if the error is a `SystemExit` (though, again, a blank `except:` or a `except Exception:` is considered bad practice):

```
try:
    ...
except SystemExit:
    pass  # ignore it
except:
    getproduct(character)
```

---

You should note, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit):

> `quit(code=None)`
> `exit(code=None)`
> Objects that when printed, print a message like “Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit”, and when called, raise SystemExit with the specified exit code.

You should probably use `sys.exit()` instead, though it does basically the same thing.